# Modify parent state from the child in expandablelistview Android

Tags: android, android-listview, expandablelistview

I'm using expandablelistview  with CursorTreeAdapter, I'm trying to change the state of a view in the parent view from the child view, is this possible?

Or is it possible for the parent of each group view to listen to a change on its children?

This is what I'm trying to do if the question isn't clear enough,

The parent has a CheckBox, and all of its children has their own check boxes, I want the parent check box state to be checked when all the children check boxes are checked.

The same goes when I have many group views, where each parent/GrouView listen to its own children.

**Update** adding code

```
public class UsersAdapter extends CursorTreeAdapter {



    public UsersAdapter(Cursor cursor, Context context, Cursor dialogCuror) {
        super(cursor, context);

    }


    protected void bindChildView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor,
            boolean arg3) {

        //this is where I use the child views including the check boxes of the children
    }

    @Override
    protected void bindGroupView(View view, Context context,
            final Cursor cursor, boolean isExpanded) {

     //This is where I use the views of the Group view including the check boxes
     // of the parent

    }

    @Override
    protected Cursor getChildrenCursor(Cursor groupCursor) {

        return new DBHelper(context).queryGroupChildren(id);
    }

    @Override
    protected View newChildView(Context context, Cursor cursor,
            boolean isLastChild, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.exp_child_item, parent, false);

    }

    @Override
    protected View newGroupView(Context context, Cursor cursor,
            boolean isExpanded, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.exp_group_item, parent, false);
    }

}
```

Comment: Have done some thing for that? then put it(code) here.

Comment: I've not, I have no idea how to start or to use what.

Comment: Post your CursorTreeAdapter and the layout code

Comment: I added it, please note that I removed many of it as it's really long.